# Get the average of one column of dates as day

Tags: sql-server

My SQL table (SQL Server structure) has a bunch of work orders tied to each of my assets with completion dates. So something like this (but like 20+ WO's for each asset):

```
WO#1      10/20/12 12:00:00 AM
WO#2      10/31/12 12:00:00 Am
```

I'm trying to create a script that will get me the average time between WO's. So I essentially need to get a sum of the differences of this date column. I figure this has some combination of `CAST`, `dateDiff`, `avg` workaround but I've tried many variations and can't seem to get it. Any thoughts?

So if i had 3 dates 10/20, 10/25, and 11/12
You'd find out theres 5 days between the first two and 18 days between the second two. I then want the average of that (5,18)=11.5

Comment: which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: which db system do you use?

Comment: Sorry its an SQL server hosted by one of our vendors

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "differences of this date column"?  If there are 1000 rows, how do you want to determine the difference between one particular date?  Do you want to compare it to the other 999 rows?  Do you just want to compare it to one particular row in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
SELECT AssetID, DATEDIFF(d, MIN(datecol), MAX(datecol)) as Days
FROM table
GROUP BY AssetID
```

will give you the number of days between your first and last work order.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't realize that a sum of differences is just the difference of the first and last.....thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this post. It is old but for anyone else that sees this the answer above is actually incorrect. Max - Min is range. `AVG` is all values added / count of values.

Get average: `CAST(AVG(CAST(yourdate AS INT)) AS DATETIME)`